# can I run custom JS file in Expo as a script in GitHub actions?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, github-actions, cicd

I have a folder `bin` and inside some script `example.js` with content

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log("Run my code!");
```

and I want to add run that script as a job in GitHub actions

```
  - name:  Install dependencies
    run: yarn install
        
  - name:  Trigger my test script
    run: yarn test
```

btw my package.json:

```
  "start": "expo start",
  "test": "./bin/example.js"
```

I am getting in the logs `Permission denied`.

My question is how can I afford this magic? Maybe Expo doesn't recognize `#!/usr/bin/env node`?

Comment: What does Expo have to do with this? Does the file have execute permission? Why not `node ./bin/example.js`?

Comment: with those questions, I resolved everything. 1. not related to Expo 2. I changed permissions on that file and 3. yes node ./bin/example.js works as expected. Thank you!

Comment: If a solution is found, write and accept your own answer below. That's how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was `jonrsharpe` comment (thank you):
instead this `"test": "./bin/example.js"` I added `"test": "node ./bin/example.js"`